# PL/SQL procedure for conversion of xml/csv/excel/flat files into xml and store in database as xml format

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I am looking for a solution where incoming payment files with xml/csv/excel/flat format needs to be converted into xml format and stored in oracle database.
Could anyone help, how we can implement this. Is all these transformations and storage possible with PL/SQL? Any sample code/procedure available?

Comment: There is a ton of XML functionality in Oracle, so yes it will be possible. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/title.htm

Comment: thanks Williams...But I am unable to find the ways to convert incoming files in excel/csv/flat filesinto xml and stored as xml in database... .Inputs => xml/csv/flat/excel files in a folder   ... Output=> all those incoming files to be converted into xml and stored in database

Comment: It sounds like your solution will need to open each file, determine what type it is, and then process accordingly. What all of that looks like really depends on the final format of your XML and the current format of the files. I don't think we have enough information to say more than that.